# Jersey ContainerResponseFilter get Request Message

Tags: spring-boot, jersey, jersey-2.0

Hi I use jersey ContainerResponseFilter and in the response I need both response and request messages ,after MyApi execution and return response then mycontainerresponsefilter is working but when I try to get request entity I got input stream closed message,how can I read input data in container responsefilter?

"Entity input stream has already been closed."

```
public Response MyApi(MyApiRequest request)
    {


        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(response).build();
    }


    >   public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext,
    > ContainerResponseContext containerResponseContext) throws IOException
    > { 
    >      ContainerRequest cr = (ContainerRequest)containerRequestContext;
    >                 cr.bufferEntity();
    >                 requestBody = (String)cr.readEntity(String.class);
```

Comment: You need to read it in a _request_ filter. Then you can set it as a property in the request context. In the response filter you can get the property. That's one way to do it.

Comment: I need both response and request in containerresponsefilter,for that reason I have to take both properties one time,do you share any code sample

Comment: What you're doing in your response filter, you will need to do in a request filter, and then use request.setProperty() to add a property with the body being the value. You can then retrieve the value in the response filter with request.getProperty()